Why the intuition simulation is wrong in "How to Simulate It" - section 8 extract input OT？
I'm reading "How to Simulate It" section 8 'Extracting Inputs – Oblivious Transfer'. It makes me confused about the security proof when $P_1$ is corrupt. I wonder when the adversary $\mathcal{A}$ determines the input $x_0$,$x_1$ and why the output $P_2$ has in the ideal model will not match $x_0$ or $x_1$?





I believe that the reason of $\mathcal{S}$ failed is due to its lack of knowledge about the input of $P_2$. In addition, the two tuples $(x_0,x_1),(x'_0,x'_1)$ generated by $\mathcal{A}$ differ in both executions. Hence, if $\mathcal{S}$ follows the described strategy, it may obtain error outputs when presented with inputs of $P_2$ opposite to those specified in the given strategy. In details, the correct extraction values through rewinding should be $(x_1,x'_0)$, however, $\mathcal{S}$ obtains the error outputs as $(x_0,x'_1)$.

@X.H.Yue Thanks for your answer! but i still confused about when and why the two tuples $(x_0,x_1),(x′_0,x′_1)$ was generated by $\mathcal{A}$,

I think the example is to demonstrate the limitation of rewinding. Generally, in the singleton model, rewinding is a popular method of extracting knowledges that $\mathcal{S}$ requires. Without the necessary knowledges, $\mathcal{S}$ cannot correctly simulate the corrputed party, allowing the distinguisher to correctly determine which world it is in with non-negligible probability. You can think of $\mathcal{A}$ as a piece of code running on $\mathcal{S}$. $\mathcal{S}$ can make a breakpoint at some line of the code, halt and record $\mathcal{A}$'s output, then run the code again.

Note, A is honest but for a) choosing $(x_0,x_1)$ using a PRF and b) literally outputting $(x_0,x_1)$ (instead of $\lambda$). Let's assume in the 1st simulated run, with $\sigma=0$,  A outputs $(1,2)$ (and $P_2$ would output $1$) and in the 2nd run $(3,4)$ ($P_2$ would output $4$). By PRF, these tuples differ with overwhelming probability.
S then sends $(1,4)$ to the ideal functionality and outputs whatever A outputs in one of the runs: Using the $(1,2)$-run, when the true σ=1, in the simulation $P_2$ outputs $4$ but in real run $2$ => distinguishable. Analogue for $(3,4)$-run and σ=0.

Just for clarification: My previous comment tends into the same direction as the first one of @X.H.Yue. However, I wanted to stress the point of $\mathcal{A}$ outputting the tuples chosen by the PRF, which makes it easy to distinguish the simulated transcripts from real ones (depending on the run chosen by $\mathcal{S}$ and true $P_2$ input $\sigma$). Also (different than suggested ?), there are no such "correct" extraction values through rewinding in this case, i.e. you could not just output $(x_1,x_0')$ as this mismatches the application of PRF. So, yes, rewinding is limited here.

when $\mathcal{S}$ internally invoke $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{S}$ can not keep the tuple $(x_0,x_1)$ the same in different excution. Am I getting it right?

Yep, since by assumption $\mathcal{A}$ samples them using a PRF on its view before the final step, all values will be (pairwise) different with overwhelming probability.

i get, thanks for your patience!
